# Python encoding issue

Tags: python

i m working with some python script, got a raw string with UTF8 encoding. first of all i decoded it to utf8 then some processing is done and at the end i encode it back to utf8 and inserted to DB(mysql) but chars in DB are not presented in real format.

```
str = '<term>Beiträge</term>'
str = str.decode('utf8')
...
...
...
str = str.encode('utf8')
```

after that string is found in txt file in its real form but in MYSQL_DB, i found it like this

```
 <term>"BeitrÃ¤ge</term>
```

any idea why this happened? :-(

Comment: check your db connection charset

Comment: `str` is not a good variable name. It hides the function `str()`. Also, use different variable names for different types of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the MySQLdb library, you need to create connections using the keyword arguments:

> **use_unicode**
>       If True, text-like columns are returned as unicode objects using the
>   connection's character set. Otherwise,
>   text-like columns are returned as
>   strings. columns are returned as
>   normal strings. Unicode objects will
>   always be encoded to the connection's
>   character set regardless of this
>   setting.
>
> &
>
> **charset**
>       If supplied, the connection character set will be changed to this
>   character set (MySQL-4.1 and newer).
>   This implies use_unicode=True.

You should also check the encoding of your db tables.

Comment: Connection's char set is utf8, and i m using MySQLdb

Comment: try utf8_bin (whatever the utf8 binary encoding is called in mysql, I didn't look it up).

Answer (score 0):

To make a string a Unicode string you should use the stringprefix 'u'. See also here http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals

Maybe your example works by just adding the prefix in the initial assignment.